# Question grammar construction

Tags: grammar

What is the grammar construction behind the following question:
Why will you need to read? For essays? For lectures? For seminars?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking about 'will'? Providing the background/context would also be extremely helpful.

Comment: @JMB Agree. This seems very cryptic, though.

Comment: These are four questions to communicate one idea. Normally, I would expect one question to communicate a single idea. Moreover, the second, third, etc. are not complete sentences. So, I am wondering about their grammar construction. Are they abbreviations of longer questions?

Comment: "For essays/lectures/seminars" give examples of why the person will need to read. Thus, the question could be phrased: "Will you need to read for essays/lectures/seminars?" Does that answer what you're asking?

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three questions involve ellipsis.  The phrases "for essays", "for lectures" and "for seminars" all represent possible answers to the first question.  They are example referents for "why".  The rest of the first question (meaning everything except the word "why") can be seen as something that's been left out of the follow-up questions, just to avoid unnecessary repetition:

> Why will you need to read?  [Will you need to read] for essays?  [Will you need to read] for lectures?  [Will you need to read] for seminars?